# Dell PowerEdge 1950 sever give me SAS drive error while i am only using sata with it

Tags: dell

As the subject stated that Dell PowerEdge 1950 sever give me SAS drive error while i am only using sata with it, then it give me option to press F1 to to continue........
Please tell me how i can remove this error?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

A SAS interface can accomodate either SAS or SATA drives; you can connect up to 4 SATA drives on one mini-SAS port (with a fanout cable).

You'll have to examine the BIOS POST message(s) in more detail - or consult the controller BIOS and event log - to find out what exactly it is saying.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the error message handling on the old Dell PowerEdge is not good and sometimes misleads. I also have the same error messages on my couple of Dell PowerEdge 1950 servers.

I have replaced the SAS cable, washed with alcohol, cleaned with vacuum cleaner but lo luck. The problem refers to SAS cable but actually problem is not SAS cable. Once couple of days later mysteriously this error message dissapeared on a system and then one week after that reappeared again. I think this problem might be caused by poor soldering.

Another a weird error message of Dell PowerEdge 1950 is "5V power grid error". I replaced the power supply but could not start my systems after this error appeared. I believe something should be corrupted on the mainboard.